# Evaluating two integrals involving $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> I want to show
> $$I:=\int_0^{1}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{8}$$
> and
> $$J:=\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}\right)dx=\pi\log \frac{3}{2}$$

My work:

Let us try to do the first one. Note that by making a change of variable $x\mapsto 1-x$ we have
$$I=\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{\frac32-x}\right)dx$$
Adding the two expression of $I$ and doing some simple algebra lead us to
$$2I=\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{3}\sqrt{x(1-x)}\right)dx$$
We can obtain similar expression for $2J$ as well. But I am not sure how to deal with this integral. The fractor $\frac{3}{8}$ looks really odd here. However, if you plug it in wolframalpha they indeed give you the desired result. I also tried substituting $x=\sin^2\theta$ or $x=\cos^2\theta$. The expression didn't simplify. Perhaps there is some clever way to do it.

Comment: Good job ! Use IBP first plus (I suppose) $x=u^2$ and (I guess) long division. Probably $u=\sin(v)$. By the way, $\to +1$.

Comment: Don't forget $\displaystyle \int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{1+x}\right)dx=\pi\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use an Euler substitution to simplify both integrals, namely: $\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x}=t\Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$.
$$I=\int_0^1\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{\frac{1}{2}+x}\right)dx=\int_0^\infty\arctan\left(\frac{2t}{3+t^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)'dt$$
$$\overset{IBP}=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{3}{9+t^2}\right)\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\color{blue}{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}dt}-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2}\frac{3}{9+t^2}dt$$
$$\overset{\color{blue}{t\to \frac{1}{t}}}=\color{blue}{\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt}+\frac{1}{8}\int_0^\infty \frac{3}{9+t^2}dt-\frac{3}{8}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

---

Similarly for the second integral we obtain:
$$J=\int_0^1\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{\frac{1}{2}+x}\right)\frac{dx}{1-x}=2\int_0^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{2t}{3+t^2}\right) \frac{1}{t(1+t^2)}dt$$
$$\overset{IBP}=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{3}{9+t^2}\right)(\ln(1+t^2)-2\ln t)dt$$
Now we can differentiate under the integral sign considering the following integral:
$$J(a)=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{3}{9+t^2}\right)(\ln(a^2+t^2)-2\ln t)dt$$
$$\Rightarrow J'(a)=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{3}{9+t^2}\right)\frac{2a}{a^2+t^2}dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1-a^2}\frac{2a}{a^2+t^2}-\frac{2a}{1-a^2}\frac{1}{1+t^2}+\frac{2a}{9-a^2}\frac{3}{9+t^2}-\frac{3}{9-a^2}\frac{2a}{a^2+t^2}\right)dt$$
$$=\pi\left(\frac{1}{1-a^2}-\frac{a}{1-a^2}+\frac{a}{9-a^2}-\frac{3}{9-a^2}\right)=\pi\left(\frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{1}{3+a}\right)$$
$$J(0)=0\Rightarrow J=\pi\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{1}{3+a}\right)da=\pi\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Comment: The Euler substitution was really illuminating. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using integration by parts and $x=\sin^2t,u=\cot t$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^{1}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}\right)dx\\
&=&x\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}\right)\bigg|_0^1-\int_0^{1}x\frac{1-4 x}{\sqrt{(1-x) x} (8 x+1)}dx\\
&=&-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2t(1-4\sin^2t)}{8\sin^2t+1}dt\\
&=&-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\csc^2t-4}{(8+\csc^2t)\csc^2t}dt\\
&=&-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cot^2t-3}{(9+\cot^2t)(1+\cot^2 t)}dt\\
&=&-2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^2-3}{(9+u^2)(1+u^2)^2}du
\end{eqnarray}
which is not hard to handle.

Answer (score 1):

The idea for the first integral is nice, we only need to use the substitution $x=\sin^2 t$ (also mentioned in the OP) from the point the OP stopped.

We will use
$$
\arctan s+\arctan t = \arctan\frac {s+t}{1-st}\ .
$$
to "combine" a sum of $\arctan$ values.
So for the first integral:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2I
&= 
\int_0^1\arctan \frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}\; dx
+
\int_0^1\arctan \frac{\sqrt{(1-x)x}}{\frac32-x}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^1\left(
\arctan \frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}
+
\arctan \frac{\sqrt{(1-x)x}}{\frac32-x}\right)
\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^1
\arctan \left(\frac 83\sqrt {x(1-x)}\right)\; dx
\\
&
\qquad\qquad\text{and we substitute $x=\sin^2t$}
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\arctan \left(\frac 83\sin t\cos t\right)\; 2\sin \cos t\; dt
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\arctan \left(\frac 43\sin 2t\right)\; \sin 2t\; dt
\\
&=
-\frac 12
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\arctan \left(\frac 43\sin 2t\right)\; (\cos 2t)'\; dt
\\
&=
-\frac 12
\left[
\arctan \left(\frac 43\sin 2t\right)\; \cos 2t
\right]_0^{\pi/2}
+
\frac 12
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\left(\arctan \left(\frac 43\sin 2t\right)\right)'\; \cos 2t\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\left(\arctan \left(\frac 43\sin 2t\right)\right)'\; \cos 2t\; dt
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\frac{24\;\cos^2 2t}{16\sin^2 2t+9}\; dt
=
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\frac{6(1+\cos 4t)}{8(1-\sin4t)+9}\; dt=\dots
\\
&=\frac\pi 4\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

For the second integral we cannot wait so long for the substitution from $x$ to $t$. After that i did it my way. (All steps are shown in detail.)
$$
\begin{aligned}
J
&= 
\int_0^1\frac 1{1-x}\arctan \frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x+\frac12}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac 1{1-\sin^2 t}\arctan \frac{\sin t\cos t}{\sin^2 t+\frac12}\; d(\sin^2t)
\\
&=
2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac {\sin t}{\cos t}
\arctan \frac{2\sin t\cos t}{2\sin^2 t+1}\; dt
\\
&
\qquad\qquad\text{and we substitute $u=\tan t$}
\\
&=
2\int_0^{\infty}u
\arctan \frac{\frac {2u}{1+u^2}}{\frac{2u^2}{1+u^2}+1}\; \frac 1{1+u^2}\;du
\\
&=
2\int_0^{\infty}
\frac u{1+u^2}
\arctan \frac{2u}{3u^2+1}\;du
\\
&=
\int_0^{\infty}
(\ \log(1+u^2)\ )'
\arctan \frac{2u}{3u^2+1}\;du
\\
&=
\left[\log(1+u^2)
\arctan \frac{2u}{3u^2+1}\right]_0^{\infty}
-
\int_0^{\infty}
\log(1+u^2)
\;\left(\ \arctan \frac{2u}{3u^2+1}\ \right)'\;du
\\
&=
\int_0^{\infty}
\log(1+u^2)
\;\frac{2(3u^2-1)}{(9u^2+1)(u^2+1)}\;du
\\
&=
\int_0^{\infty}
\log(1+u^2)
\;\left[
\frac1{u^2+1}
-
\frac3{9u^2+1}
\right]
\;du
\\
&=
\pi \log\left(1+\frac 11\right)
-
\pi \log\left(1+\frac 13\right)
\\
&={\color{blue}{\pi \log\frac 32}}\ ,
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\qquad\text{if we show the equality $(!)$}
\\
K(a)&=
\int_0^{\infty}
\log(1+u^2)\cdot 
\frac a{a^2u^2+1}
\;du
\
{\color{red}{\overset{(!)}{=\!=}}}
\
\pi\log\left(1+\frac 1a\right)\ .
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\qquad\text{After $v=au$, with $b=1/a$, we show equivalently:}
\\
K\left(\frac 1b\right)&=
\int_0^{\infty}
\log(1+b^2v^2)\cdot 
\frac 1{v^2+1}
\;dv
\
{\color{red}{\overset{(!)}{=\!=}}}
\
\pi\log\left(1+b\right)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The above marked relation ${\color{red}{\overset{(!)}{=\!=}}}$ holds in $b=0$, and after we differentiate on both sides w.r.t. $b$, it remains to show:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}
\underbrace{
\frac {2b\;v^2}{b^2v^2+1}\cdot 
\frac 1{v^2+1}
}_{=\frac {2b}{b^2-1}\left(\frac 1{v^2+1}-\frac 1{b^2v^2+1}\right)}
\;dv
\
{\color{red}{\overset{(!)}{=\!=}}}
\
\frac \pi{1+b}\ .
$$
For this, use the shown partial fraction decomposition, integrate then to obtain $
\frac {2b}{b^2-1}\left(\frac \pi 2-\frac \pi{2b}\right)$.

$\square$